# ExceptionAddress is 0 in windbg

Tags: windbg

When I run `!analyze -v` in Windbg, I find below output:

```
FAULTING_IP:
+0
00000000`00000000     ??           ???

EXCEPTION_RECORD: (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 0000000000000000
    ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
    ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

FAULTING_THREAD: 00000eac
```

The `ExceptionAddress` is 0. 
Also, the `Faulting_IP` is wired too.
Can anybody tell me what it means? Thanks!

Full report of `!analyze -v`

```
0:000> !analyze -v 
***********************************************************************
* *
* Exception Analysis *
* *
***********************************************************************

GetUrlPageData2 (WinHttp) failed: 12029. 
Debugger WatsonDb Connection::Open failed 80004005

DUMP_CLASS: 2

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

FAULTING_IP: 
+0 
00000000`00000000     ??         ??? 

EXCEPTION_RECORD: (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 0000000000000000
ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

FAULTING_THREAD: 00000eac

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID: STATUS_BREAKPOINT

PROCESS_NAME: MyApp.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 - {EXCEPTION} Breakpoint A breakpoint has been reached.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (HRESULT) 0x80000003 (2147483651) - One or more arguments are invalid

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR: 80000003

WATSON_BKT_PROCSTAMP: 5541d928

WATSON_BKT_PROCVER: 6.0.1108.7962

PROCESS_VER_PRODUCT: My Application

WATSON_BKT_MODULE: unknown

WATSON_BKT_MODVER: 0.0.0.0

WATSON_BKT_MODOFFSET: 0

WATSON_BKT_MODSTAMP: bbbbbbb4

BUILD_VERSION_STRING: 6.1.7601.18933 (win7sp1_gdr.150715-0600)

MODLIST_WITH_TSCHKSUM_HASH: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

MODLIST_SHA1_HASH: xxxxxxxxxxxxx

NTGLOBALFLAG: 0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS: 0

PRODUCT_TYPE: 3

SUITE_MASK: 400

DUMP_FLAGS: 8000c07

DUMP_TYPE: 0

APP: MyApp.exe

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST: MyMachine

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME: 12-14-2015 12:56:53.0773

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.11075.859 amd64fre

MANAGED_CODE: 1

MANAGED_ENGINE_MODULE: clr

MANAGED_ANALYSIS_PROVIDER: SOS

MANAGED_THREAD_ID: eac

THREAD_ATTRIBUTES: 
OS_LOCALE: ENU

PROBLEM_CLASSES: 

Tid [0x0]
Frame [0x00]
String [STATUS_BREAKPOINT]
Data Bucketing

BUGCHECK_STR: STATUS_BREAKPOINT

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER: from 000007fefd1610dc to 000000007712d9fa

STACK_TEXT: 
00000000`0030e268 000007fe`fd1610dc : 00000001`40096780 00000000`770ffa55 00000001`40c1e6f8 000007fe`ff083858 : ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xa
00000000`0030e270 000007fe`ff08affb : 00000000`ffffffff 000007fe`ff08344c 00000000`00000000 00000000`0000025c : KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x79
00000000`0030e310 000007fe`ff089d61 : 00000000`00508e60 00000000`0000025c 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : sechost!ScSendResponseReceiveControls+0x13b
00000000`0030e400 000007fe`ff089c16 : 00000000`0030e568 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : sechost!ScDispatcherLoop+0x121
00000000`0030e510 00000001`40097688 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00537280 00000000`004fd020 00000000`00000001 : sechost!StartServiceCtrlDispatcherW+0x14e
00000000`0030e560 00000001`3fe95562 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 000007ff`00000000 : MyApp!wmain+0x248
00000000`0030e850 000007fe`f3d617c7 : 00000000`004e7380 000007fe`f3d6d8b7 00000000`00000000 ffffffff`fffffffe : MyApp__tmainCRTStartup+0x11a
00000000`0030e880 000007ff`00255204 : 00000000`00000000 000007ff`001c9d50 00000000`0030eb38 00000000`0030e958 : clr!DoNDirectCall__PatchGetThreadCall+0x7b
00000000`0030e920 000007fe`f3dba9f4 : 13a15f0d`25725be9 00000001`3fdf71e2 13a15eff`0000cf26 000007ff`0003b280 : DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke()+0x34
00000000`0030e9e0 000007fe`f3dbab09 : 00000000`0030ea70 000007fe`f3d64d95 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : clr!CallDescrWorker+0x84
00000000`0030ea20 000007fe`f3dbab85 : 00000000`0030eb38 00000000`00000000 00000000`0030eb40 00000000`0030ed58 : clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0xa9
00000000`0030eaa0 000007fe`f3dbafdc : 00000000`0030ed58 000007ff`002066e0 00000000`0030ee20 000007fe`f3d6cd9c : clr!MethodDesc::CallDescr+0x2a1
00000000`0030ecd0 000007fe`f3e6530a : 00000000`00000000 00000000`0030f060 00000000`0030ed68 00000000`00000000 : clr!MethodDesc::CallTargetWorker+0x44
00000000`0030ed10 000007fe`f3f50200 : 00000000`004e7380 00000000`004e7380 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : clr!ClassLoader::RunMain+0x276
00000000`0030ef60 000007fe`f3f502b5 : 00000000`0030f560 00000000`00000200 00000000`004fc950 00000000`00000200 : clr!Assembly::ExecuteMainMethod+0xac
00000000`0030f210 000007fe`f3f505e6 : 00000000`00000000 00000001`3fa70000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : clr!SystemDomain::ExecuteMainMethod+0x468
00000000`0030f7c0 000007fe`f3f50503 : 00000001`3fa70000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : clr!ExecuteEXE+0x43
00000000`0030f820 000007fe`f3f0b649 : 00000000`004e7380 ffffffff`ffffffff 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : clr!_CorExeMainInternal+0xc4
00000000`0030f890 000007fe`f8e63309 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`0030f878 : clr!_CorExeMain+0x15
00000000`0030f8d0 000007fe`f8ef5b21 : 000007fe`f3f0b634 000007fe`f8e632c0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : mscoreei!_CorExeMain+0x41
00000000`0030f900 00000000`76ed5a4d : 000007fe`f8e60000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : mscoree!_CorExeMain_Exported+0x57
00000000`0030f930 00000000`7710b831 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
00000000`0030f960 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d

STACK_COMMAND: ~0s; .ecxr ; kb

RETRACER_ANALYSIS_TAG_STATUS: DEBUG_FLR_EXCEPTION_CODE is not 0xc0000005

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC: 6a9340d603e3e3866649a6a0d84790917bb6dd03

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET: a1c2d97877512bc7d9699a841301060ee3830e4f

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD: 3779b2e875e4d590e4afafeeeacc4c93bff23146

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
sechost!ScSendResponseReceiveControls+13b [d:\win7_rtm\minkernel\screg\sc\client\lib\minwin\scapi.cxx @ 3379]
000007fe`ff08affb 85c0 test eax,eax

FAULT_INSTR_CODE: 4f74c085

FAULTING_SOURCE_LINE: d:\win7_rtm\minkernel\screg\sc\client\lib\minwin\scapi.cxx

FAULTING_SOURCE_FILE: d:\win7_rtm\minkernel\screg\sc\client\lib\minwin\scapi.cxx

FAULTING_SOURCE_LINE_NUMBER: 3379

FAULTING_SOURCE_CODE: 
No source found for 'd:\win7_rtm\minkernel\screg\sc\client\lib\minwin\scapi.cxx'

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX: 2

SYMBOL_NAME: sechost!ScSendResponseReceiveControls+13b

FOLLOWUP_NAME: wintriag

MODULE_NAME: sechost

IMAGE_NAME: sechost.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP: 4a5be05e

BUCKET_ID: X64_STATUS_BREAKPOINT_sechost!ScSendResponseReceiveControls+13b

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS: X64_STATUS_BREAKPOINT_sechost!ScSendResponseReceiveControls+13b

FAILURE_EXCEPTION_CODE: 80000003

BUCKET_ID_MODULE_STR: sechost

FAILURE_FUNCTION_NAME: ScSendResponseReceiveControls

BUCKET_ID_FUNCTION_STR: ScSendResponseReceiveControls

BUCKET_ID_OFFSET: 13b

BUCKET_ID_MODTIMEDATESTAMP: 4a5be05e

BUCKET_ID_MODCHECKSUM: 2b43a

BUCKET_ID_MODVER_STR: 6.1.7600.16385

BUCKET_ID_PREFIX_STR: X64_STATUS_BREAKPOINT_

FAILURE_PROBLEM_CLASS: STATUS_BREAKPOINT

FAILURE_SYMBOL_NAME: sechost.dll!ScSendResponseReceiveControls

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID: STATUS_BREAKPOINT_80000003_sechost.dll!ScSendResponseReceiveControls

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL: xxxxxxxx

TARGET_TIME: 2015-10-25T06:06:55.000Z

OSBUILD: 7601

OSSERVICEPACK: 18933

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

OSPLATFORM_TYPE: x64

OSNAME: Windows 7

OSEDITION: Windows 7 Server (Service Pack 1) TerminalServer DataCenter SingleUserTS

USER_LCID: 0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP: 2015-07-16 02:07:42

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR: 150715-0600

BUILDLAB_STR: win7sp1_gdr

BUILDOSVER_STR: 6.1.7601.18933

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME: 3c73

ANALYSIS_SOURCE: UM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING: um:status_breakpoint_80000003_sechost.dll!scsendresponsereceivecontrols

FAILURE_ID_HASH: {bb63494f-e1c6-d49e-12fa-866691bbfd47}

FAILURE_ID_REPORT_LINK: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Followup: wintriag
---------
```

Comment: Someone set EIP to 0

Comment: What Thomas said.  This is probably caused by a corrupt stack that caused a ret to 0.

Comment: Thank you both, but RIP is 7712d9fa, not 0..

Comment: Could you post the complete report from `!analyze`? It might simply be a hung thread...

Comment: My guess is that RIP is not 0 because it's the RIP in the exception handling code. If you use `kn` and then `.frame /c /r <frame>` where `<frame>` is the stack frame where the exception occurred, RIP may very well be 0.

Comment: @Neitsa, thanks for your comment. Yes, it's a hung dump. But not sure how to find the cause. I have post the full report of `!analyze -v`, could help take a look, thanks!

Comment: @MarcSherman, thanks for your reply. I have checked all the frames, no RIP is 0.

Comment: You should try one of `~.kb` ; `~#kb` ; `~*kb` (current thread; thread that caused the exception; all threads in the process) ; to see which thread is the culprit (probably thread `0xeac` but double checking doesn't harm). Then try a hang bang analyze: `!analyze -hang -v` after having determined the problematic thread. This should give a lot more info. Also take a look at handle `0x25c` it looks like the thread is waiting for it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic failure 80004005 is E_FAIL and 80000003 is a breakpoint exception, something executed a int 3 or we manually broke in!!  This app contains clr on the stack you may want to relate the failure to the .NET context as well.